# Merging CustomKeyboard onClick and ToggleButton

Tags: java

Right now I have a `CustomKeyboard class(view)` and I have Custom Chinese Characters in it.

I have several `ToggleButton` too. I want to implement something such that if I were to click the Chinese Option for Chinese Keyboard, it will toggle my toggleButton to "ON".
But I'm not sure how do I link them together.

```
//CustomKeyboard.java/class - This is the java file that is use for my CustomKeyboardView. This works when onClick on the Keyboard itself, it'll change the keyboard view etc.

private OnKeyboardActionListener noncapitalKeyboard = new OnKeyboardActionListener() {
        public final static int CodeNext     = 55005;
        public final static int CodeClear    = 55006;
        public final static int CodeCapital  = 55007;
        public final static int CodeSymbol   = 55008;
        public final static int CodeABC      = 55009;
        public final static int CodeChinese1 = 55010;



        @Override public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in primaryCode
            // Get the EditText and its Editable
            View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
            if( focusCurrent==null || focusCurrent.getClass()!=EditText.class ) return;
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();
            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if(primaryCode == CodeCapital){
                mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.keyboardview);
                mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, R.xml.capitalkeyboard));
                mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
                mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(capitalKeyboard);
            }else if(primaryCode == CodeSymbol){
                mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.keyboardview);
                mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, R.xml.symbolkeyboard));
                mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
                mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(symbolKeyboard);
            }else if(primaryCode == CodeChinese1){
                mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.keyboardview);
                mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, R.xml.chinese1keyboard));
                mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
                mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(chinese1Keyboard);
            }
```

But on my main UI Thread, how do I bring over like

```
if(primaryCode == CodeChinese1){
    toggleButton1.setChecked(true);
}
```

I tried to implement OnKeyboardActionListener on my main java file, but it didn't work because it has no reference to my CustomKeyboard. Do I need to create an interface?

Comment: This is java not javascript.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Sorry . I misclick the Tags.

Comment: No worries, just thought I would point it out asap, plus I was searching to answer javascript questions and this popped up lol. I took a java course but I am no expert haha good luck!